How is Gini impurity related to accuracy when predicting the majority class?
For simplicity, consider the binary case, where we have a set of elements with each element belonging to one of two classes (0 or 1). Let p(j) be the proportion of elements in the set that are of class j, j=0,1. The Gini impurity is the probability that the class of a randomly selected element from the set is predicted incorrectly, when the predicted class j is chosen with probability p(j), j=0,1. Therefore, 1-Gini is the probability that the class of a randomly selected element is predicted correctly (i.e., the accuracy) for this manner of prediction.
Classification trees are grown by recursively partitioning the set of elements into two subsets, where the weighted average of the Gini impurities of the resulting subsets is minimized.
However, the manner of prediction is usually to predict the majority class of the set (or subset). Does a partition that minimizes the weighted average of the Gini impurities of the resulting subsets ensure that the accuracy, when predicting the majority class of each subset, is maximized?

The short answer is no.
Consider two short trees with a root and two nodes (stumps) described by their 1/0 proportions:
Tree 1: [30/10] -- [10/30]

Accuracy:

Left node: $\frac{30}{40} = 0.75$
Right node: $\frac{30}{40} = 0.75$
Mean accuracy = $(1/2) \times 0.75 + (1/2) \times 0.75 = 0.75$


Gini impurity:

Left node: $1 - \left(\frac{30}{40}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{10}{40}\right)^2 = 0.375$
Right node:  $1 - \left(\frac{10}{40}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{30}{40}\right)^2 = 0.375$
Mean Gini impurity = $(1/2) \times 0.375 + (1/2) \times 0.375 = 0.375$



Tree 2: [39/01] -- [20/20]

Accuracy:

Left node: $\frac{39}{40} = 0.975$
Right node: $\frac{20}{40} = 0.5$
Mean accuracy = $(1/2) \times 0.975 + (1/2) \times 0.5 = 0.7375$


Gini impurity:

Left node: $1 - \left(\frac{39}{40}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{40}\right)^2 = 0.0515$
Right node: $1 - \left(\frac{20}{40}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{20}{40}\right)^2 = 0.5$
Mean Gini impurity = $(1/2) \times 0.0515 + (1/2) \times 0.5 = 0.27575$




The longer answer is the tree building based on Gini impurity the OP describes often arises in a Machine Learning context. Then, there is no guarantee that maximizing realized accuracy is the best way to achieve your ultimate goal of maximizing out-of-sample accuracy.
As the OP noted, the splits are based in observed proportions within each class out of a particular sample of unknown size $n$ (as opposed to conditional probabilities within each class). Shaping the tree to maximize accuracy on these proportions runs the risk of overfitting generating a tree that does not generalize well to new out-of-sample observations.
For example consider:
Tree 1: [22/18] -- [18/22]

Accuracy:

Left node: $\frac{22}{40} = 0.55$
Right node: $\frac{22}{40} = 0.55$
Mean accuracy = $(1/2) \times 0.55 + (1/2) \times 0.55 = 0.55$


Gini impurity:

Left node: $1 - \left(\frac{22}{40}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{18}{40}\right)^2 = 0.495$
Right node: $1 - \left(\frac{18}{40}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{22}{40}\right)^2 = 0.495$
Mean Gini impurity = $(1/2) \times 0.495 + (1/2) \times 0.495 = 0.495$




Tree 2: [24/16] -- [20/20]

Accuracy:

Left node: $\frac{24}{40} = 0.6$
Right node: $\frac{20}{40} = 0.5$
Mean accuracy = $(1/2) \times 0.6 + (1/2) \times 0.5 = 0.55$


Gini impurity:

Left node: $1 - \left(\frac{24}{40}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{16}{40}\right)^2 = 0.45$
Right node: $1 - \left(\frac{20}{40}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{20}{40}\right)^2 = 0.5$
Mean Gini impurity = $(1/2) \times 0.45 + (1/2) \times 0.5 = 0.475$



Accuracy suggests you should be indifferent between the two trees.
However, in the first tree, there is a "good chance" that either of [22/18] or [18/22] are realization flukes that do not generalize. For example, there is "decent chance" that the true conditional probability of "success" ($j=1$ in the OP's description) in the [22/18] group is below $0.5$ and classifying all future elements in that group as "successes" is worse than random classification.
In contrast, it's "less likely" for $[24/16]$ to be the result of a group with probability of success below $0.5$. A $[24/16]$ group makes you more confident that characterizing all future members of that group as "successes" will improve your prediction (over random classification).
It's no guarantee to succeed but ML practice suggests that, to some extent, it's better to take a cleaner split that's more "likely" to generalize (to out-of-sample data) than two murkier ones that are more "likely" to be idiosyncrasies of the realized sample.

For more on the topic, see for instance Elements of Statistical Learning (https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print12_toc.pdf.download.html) around pg. 360 (maybe slightly different depending on the edition you have):

"We classify the observations in node $m$ to class $k(m) = \arg\max_k
> \hat{p}_{mk}$, the majority class in node $m$. Different measures
$Q_m(T)$ of node impurity include the following:

Misclassification error:
$1 - \hat{p}_{mk(m)} = \frac{1}{N_m} \sum_{i \in R_m} \mathbb{I}(y_i
> \neq k(m)).$

Gini index: $   \sum_{k \neq k'} \hat{p}_{mk} \hat{p}_{mk'} = \sum_{k=1}^K \hat{p}_{mk} (1 - \hat{p}_{mk}). $

Cross-entropy or deviance: $   -\sum_{k=1}^K \hat{p}_{mk} \log \hat{p}_{mk}. $


For two classes, if $p$ is the proportion in the second class, these
three measures are $1 - \max(p, 1 - p)$, $2p(1-p)$, and $-p\log p -
> (1-p)\log(1-p)$, respectively. They are shown in Figure 9.3. All three
are similar, but cross-entropy and the Gini index are differentiable,
and hence more amenable to numerical optimization.
Comparing equations (9.13) and (9.15), we see that we need to weight
the node impurity measures by the number $N_{mL}$ and $N_{mR}$ of
observations in the two child nodes created by splitting node $m$.
In addition, cross-entropy and the Gini index are more sensitive to
changes in the node probabilities than the misclassification rate. For
example, in a two-class problem with 400 observations in each class
(denoted by $(400, 400)$), suppose one split creates nodes $(300,
> 100)$ and $(100, 300)$, while another split creates nodes $(200, 400)$
and $(200, 0)$. Both splits produce a misclassification rate of 0.25,
but the second split produces a pure node and is probably preferable.
Both the Gini index and cross-entropy are lower for the second split.
For this reason, either the Gini index or cross-entropy should be used
when growing the tree. To guide cost-complexity pruning, any of the
three measures can be used, but typically it is the misclassification
rate.
The Gini index can be interpreted in two interesting ways. Rather than
classify observations to the majority class in the node, we could
classify them to class $k$ with probability $\hat{p}_{mk}$. Then the
training error rate of this rule in the node is $\sum_{k \neq k'}
> \hat{p}_{mk} \hat{p}_{mk'}$—the Gini index. Similarly, if we code each
observation as 1 for class $k$ and 0 otherwise, the variance over the
node of this 0-1 response is $\hat{p}_{mk}(1 - \hat{p}_{mk})$. Summing
over classes $k$ again gives the Gini index."


Also see the end of this answer for a similar explanation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/445625/276338
